# Quantum algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's suppose that we have a quantum superposition state, and for a basis vector $|\Psi\rangle\in \mathcal{H}$,

$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi_c\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle$$

Where $|\Psi_c\rangle$ is orthogonal quantum state to $|\Psi\rangle$.

And our unitary operators are:

$$U_{\Psi} = I-2|\Psi\rangle \langle\Psi|$$

$$U_{\psi} = -I+2|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$$

Could we compute the explicit action of $(U_{\psi}U_{\Psi})(\psi) = U_{\psi}(U_{\Psi}(\psi))$ as follows?

$$\begin{align}U_{\Psi}\biggr(\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi_c\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\biggr) = \biggr(I-2|\Psi\rangle \langle\Psi|\biggr)\biggr(\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi_c\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\biggr) = |\psi\rangle -\frac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\end{align}$$

$$U_{\psi}\biggr(|\psi\rangle -\frac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\biggr) = \biggr(-I + 2|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|\biggr)\biggr(|\psi\rangle -\frac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\biggr) = |\psi\rangle + \frac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle$$

Comment: $\Psi$ is the same as $\psi$?

Comment: @FallenApart: No. $\Psi$ is one of two orthogonal basis functions, and $\psi$ is a linear combination of $\Psi$ and $\Psi_c$.

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't understand your question. Like, $\Psi$ is just a basis vector in $2$-dimensional Hilbert space, and $\psi$ is a quantum superposition state.

Comment: @joriki That's exactly what I meant, sure.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one line

Comment: @Yau: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is correct, but there may be a sign error in your second operator, which may make it wrong. **Edit: the question has since been corrected, so I have nothing to disagree with. I'll still leave my answer for completeness.**

The point of Grover's algorithm is to increase the probability of finding your state $|\psi\rangle$ in a given desired state $|\Psi\rangle$ that you want, once you do measurements. And the way you do that is by consecutively applying **unitary operators**, so that they do not change the norm of the states they act on (and hence, preserve probabilities).

Now, your first operator **is** unitary, but the second ($U_\psi = -2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ - I) isn't (you can check that $U_\psi U_\psi^\dagger \ne I$. Instead, I'm pretty sure it should be $U_\psi = 2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| - I$. Let me explain:

---

So our goal is to increase the probability of finding the state $|\psi\rangle$ in $|\Psi\rangle$, by applying unitary operators at each step. Our first step is gonna be to "single out the $|\Psi\rangle$ component", and our second step is gonna be to "amplify it".

- first, single out the state $|\Psi\rangle$ by applying the operator $U_\Psi = I - 2|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$, which will "single" out the "$|\Psi\rangle$"-components by making them negative. In your case, you are right:

$\begin{align}U_{\Psi}\biggr(\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi_c\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\biggr) = \biggr(I-2|\Psi\rangle \langle\Psi|\biggr)\biggr(\frac{\sqrt{N-1}}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi_c\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\biggr) = |\psi\rangle -\frac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle\end{align}$

- then, what you usually do, is that you apply an operator of the form $V_s= 2|s\rangle\langle s| - I$, where $|s\rangle$ is the symmetric superposition of all basis states (I'm using $V$ instead of $U$ so that we don't get confused with two many $U$'s). Now, as it happens, $|s\rangle$ is also the state $|\psi\rangle$ which you are applying Grover's algorithm on. So, applying this operator to our newfound expression:

$V_\psi(U_\Psi|\psi\rangle) = (2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| - I)(|\psi\rangle -\frac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle) = 2|\psi\rangle - \dfrac{4||\Psi||^2\langle\psi|\Psi\rangle}{\sqrt{N}}|\psi\rangle - |\psi\rangle + \dfrac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle$

Now, computing $\langle\psi|\Psi\rangle = 1/\sqrt{N}$, we get:

$V_\psi(U_\Psi|\psi\rangle) = (1 - \dfrac{4||\Psi||^2}{N})|\psi\rangle + \dfrac{2||\Psi||^2}{\sqrt{N}}|\Psi\rangle$

Let's express that back in the original $|\Psi_c\rangle, |\Psi\rangle$ (assuming that this basis is orthonormal so that $||\Psi|| = 1$).

Then we get:

$V_\psi(U_\Psi|\psi\rangle) = \left(1-\dfrac{4}{N}\right)\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{N-1}{N}}\right) |\Psi_c\rangle + \left(\dfrac{N-4}{N\sqrt{N}} + \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{N}}\right)|\Psi\rangle$

You can check that this new state still has **norm $1$**, which is thanks to the fact that we were using **unitary operators**. And in particular, the probability of finding it in $|\Psi\rangle$ when measuring has increased (it's bigger than our original $1/N$), while the probability of finding the it in $|\Psi_c\rangle$ has decreased.

Now, you can apply that algorithm repeatedly to keep increasing the probability at your will.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: But is it not true that $\dfrac{4||\Psi||^2\langle\psi|\Psi\rangle}{\sqrt{N}} = 0$, since the superposition quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|\Psi\rangle$?

Comment: @Yau: No, it's not – it has a component orthogonal to $\Psi$ (along $\Psi_c)$ and a component along $\Psi$.

Comment: Ahh, of course, my apologies for that.

Comment: @joriki the operator in question is $-I - 2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, I changed it to $-I + 2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. I didn't just "multiply by $-1$", so I'm pretty sure it does change unitarity.

Comment: If you carry out the computations, since $|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$ is symmetric, it is its own Hermitian conjugate. And $(2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| - I)^2 = I$, while this is not the case for $(-2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| - I)^2$

Comment: I've deleted my comments about the previous version of your answer to reduce the clutter – perhaps you want to delete yours, too. (I'll delete this one, too.)